# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3730 Cannot drop table 'questionnaires'

Tags: laravel

Estoy intentando hacer un rollback de mis tablas, porque necesito actualizar las tablas, sin embargo cuando estoy ejecuto `php artisan migrate:rollback` obtengo este error.

Agrego la estructura de mis migraciones:

```
create_users_tables.php
create_questions_table.php
create_answers_table.php
create_questionnaires_table.php
add_to_user_id_to_questionnaires_table.php
add_to_questionnaire_id_to_questions_table.php
```

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3730 Cannot drop table 'questionnaires' referenced by a foreign key constraint 'questions_questionnaire_id_foreign' on table 'questions'. (SQL: drop table if exists `questionnaires`)
```

El error me dice que no se puede eliminar la FK de questionnaires. Mis tablas son las siguientes:

Questionnaires

```
class CreateQuestionnairesTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::create('questionnaires', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

      $table->string('title');
      $table->string('description');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  public function down(){
    Schema::dropIfExists('questionnaires');
  }
}
```

Questions

```
class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('questionnaire_id');

      $table->text('description');
      $table->text('iframe');
      $table->text('image')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
    });
  }

  public function down(){
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('questionnaire_id');
      $table->dropForeign('questions_questionnaire_id_foreign');
    });
    Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
  }
}
```

y la tabla donde hago el alter table para agregar la fk a questionnaire.

```
class AddToQuestionnaireIdToQuestionsTable extends Migration{
  public function up(){
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->foreign('questionnaire_id')->references('id')->on('questionnaires')
        ->onDelete('cascade')
        ->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
  }
  public function down(){
    Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->dropColumn('questionnaire_id');
    });
  }
}
```

Sin embargo, no logro hacer el rollback como se debe ¿En que estoy fallando?

Comment: Prueba en la migración donde tienes la llave foránea agregarle el método `->onDelete('cascade')`

Comment: Ya esta agregada. `$table->foreign('questionnaire_id')->references('id')->on('questionnaires')->onDelete('cascade')`o  ¿A cuál dices?

Comment: Me refería en el create de la migración en lugar de la migración donde modificas

Comment: por la estructura de mis tablas, ya agregue esa info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me olvido agregarlo pero, pude solucionar al hacer lo siguiente:

- Una vez ejecutado el comando `php artisan migrate:rollback`, ir la base de datos y borrar las tablas que habían quedado (junto con la tabla migrations) ya que esa es la que daba errores... Al parecer el ORM se "buggeo" y no fue hasta que elimine todo ello para esto funcionará.

Un poco visceral pero, como estaba usando datos de prueba no tuve problema alguno, ya que todo los datos eran datos semillas. Espero que le sirva a alguno.